# How to handle promises which can cause deadlocks

Tags: node.js, promise, deadlock

Lets say I have a nodejs application with a critical section in, where I want to regulate the access on a few data structures. In this section I use a promise to create a rest call to a server and I need the respond to decide how to exit from this critical section. In the promise itself, I have to use a library which still uses callbacks. In very few cases the server seems to be overloaded and I didn't get a response at all. As an result the application is stuck inside the promise and therefore inside the critical section, which leads to a deadlock. Is there any way to prevent such behavior? Is it a good approach to just add a *setTimeout* to the web request and cancel the timeout on a response?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps set a timeout https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/01/16/timeout-promises-nodejs/

Comment: If you legitmately sometimes don't get a response from the other server, then the only solution is a timeout.   But, you shouldn't be blocking a critical section while waiting for an external request anyway as that probably wrecks the scalability of your server.  There are probably bigger design changes needed to find the best solution.

Comment: Why do you have to use an outdated library to make the request? There are numerous updated libraries which use promises.

Comment: Any plain callback API can be easily wrapped in a promise so that should not be a contributor to the problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the comment from @IronMan I created a solution using `promise.race` and wrap the function which is doing the rest call:

```
Promise.race([
  _promiseDoingRestCall(data),
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("Timeout")), 30000)),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use SetTimeout.

```js
new Promise((Resolve,Reject) => {
    doHttpRequest(callback)
    // if it takes too long, we will reject before it is resolved.
    setTimeout(() => { Reject("Timeout") },3000)
})
```

Comment: Uhhh, the callback needs to be linked into the promise too.